# inserting lotus database link into mail html sigature

Tags: html, hyperlink, lotus-notes

I have a following issue with my Lotus Notes.
A mail signature in my Lotus client is taken from html file.
Now I have to insert into my signature an active (clickable) link to Lotus database in format Notes://server/replica.
Unfortunately a link inserted as

```
<a href="Notes://server/replica">some text</a>
```

doesn't work.
Please suggest me is it possible to insert an active Lotus link into html formatted file.

Thank you,
Tomasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work the way you showed in your code.

There is only a pitfall for testing: the link doesn't work if mail is in **edit** mode. But, if you send the mail or save it as draft and open it in **read** mode then the link does work.

Of course it will only work if mail receiver has a Notes client installed and has access to your Notes server.